# How to print the word in audio file

Tags: java, arrays, speech-recognition, audio-recording, audio

I did a small application that can capture sounds from my computer. The simple process of the system is when I played a music file it will capture the voice and when I playback the captured thing,it will playback. Totally everything works fine. Now what I want to do is I want to print the play back. Just assume that I capture a voice like "Hi,Good morning",now when I press the play back it should have to print the recorded thing in text. Capture and playback coding as below.

```
private void captureAudio() {
    try {
        final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);

        line.start();
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
            byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

            public void run() {

                out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                running = true;
                try {
                    while (running) {
                        int count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        if (count > 0) {
                            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }                            
                    }
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("I/O problems: " + e);
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread captureThread = new Thread(runner);
        captureThread.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        System.err.println("Line unavailable: " + e);
        System.exit(-2);
    }
}  


private void playAudio() {
    try {
        byte audio[] = out.toByteArray();

        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(audio);
        final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
        final AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(input, format, audio.length / format.getFrameSize());
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        final SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
            byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

            public void run() {

                try {
                    int count;
                    while ((count = ais.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                        if (count > 0) {
                            line.write(buffer, 0, (char)count);
                            System.out.print((char)count);

                        }
                    }
                    line.drain();
                    line.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("I/O problems: " + e);
                    System.exit(-3);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread playThread = new Thread(runner);
        playThread.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        System.err.println("Line unavailable: " + e);
        System.exit(-4);
    }
}
```

Please someone advice / help me to overcome from this.
Thank you.

Comment: 1) What you want is speech recognition, but I doubt it will be possible to put that information into the resulting audio file.  2) Please *read* the tag pop-ups before applying them to a question, this has nothing to do with 'audio streaming'.

Comment: Probably look into the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-doc/) and [Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Thanks for the comment dude. I already did the speech recognition part and 100% working fine. but in here the thing is there is no speaking part. Its about playing an audio. To recognize the speech there should have some input to the target data line. Thats the point I am currently stucked. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CMU sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)! In order to be able to convert the captured audion to speech, you can use the Sphinx api. However kindly note that the accuracy of speech recognition is not so much to help you as the system is still under development.In android, you can use speech recognition from [google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) which has a fair [accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#Accuracy).But still that wont convert your captured voice to speech with desired accuracy. So better have a fixed lyric text which is displayed at the speed of playing of the audio.

Hope that helped!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, post a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @jlordo I have worked with sphinx and I know its pros and cons very well.Anyways I would surely include some more info and links.Thanx anyways!!

Comment: I gone through the CMU Sphinx and did some part with it. please just check my above comment. I mentioned my problem clearly there. Thanks @jlordo sorry bro at the moment I dont have the reference link, but be honest I get this code from the internet and make some modifications according to my need. I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: In the playAudio() method, is there any way to print the ByteArrayOutputStream ? if there is a way, thats a goal. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Good solution BTW.